# Implicit conversion to supertype using type classes

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit-conversion

Why does foo1 fail and foo2 succeeds?  Shouldn't the compiler automatically check all the supertypes of Blah?

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def bar: A
}

trait Bleh;
case class Blah extends Bleh;
implicit object BlehFoo extends Foo[Bleh]

def foo1[A:Foo](a:A) = a

def foo2[A,B:Foo](a:A)(implicit aToB: A => B) = aToB(a)

// Shouldn't it automatically use Bleh?
foo1(Blah())
// Failure: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Foo[Blah]

foo2(Blah())
// Success: Bleh = Blah()
```

Comment: Good question, but the variable names you chose make me want to vomit. Couldn't they have been more descriptive, like SuperClass/SubClass?

Comment: `Foo`, `Bar`, etc are perfectly standard (and loved) in the industry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `Foo[Bleh]` as `Foo[Blah]` since `Foo[Bleh]` is not a `Foo[Blah]`. You should make `Foo` contravariant on `A` to use `Foo[Bleh]` as `Foo[Blah]`.

```
trait Foo[-A] {
  def bar(a: A) = println(a) // to make Foo contravariant 
}
```

This works just fine:

```
scala> foo1(Blah())
res0: Blah = Blah()
```

Your original code contains an answer to your question. Let's assume you could use your original `Foo[Bleh]` as `Foo[Blah]`:

```
def foo1[A:Foo](): A = implicitly[Foo[A]].bar

val b: Blah = foo1[Blah]()
```

In case `Foo[Bleh]` is used here you'll get `Bleh` as result of `bar`, but you are expecting `Blah` and `Bleh` is not a `Blah`.

Fortunately compiler will not allow you to use your original `Foo[Bleh]` as `Foo[Blah]`:

```
scala> trait Foo[-A] {
     |   def bar: A
     | }
<console>:8: error: contravariant type A occurs in covariant position in type => A of method bar
         def bar: A
             ^
```

**Type inference**

This works fine:

```
foo1[Bleh](Blah())
```

But compiler will not infer type parameter `A` here as `Bleh`. In order to understand "why" we should know what `A:Foo` means:

```
def foo1[A:Foo](a:A) = a // syntax sugar
def foo1[A](a:A)(implicit ev: Foo[A]) = a // same method
```

`A:Foo` is a syntax sugar for addition implicit parameter.

If you have 2 parameter groups compiler will infer type in first group and then considers that types known. So after type inference on first parameter group `(a:A)` type `Blah` is known and second parameter group can't affect on type parameter.

Comment: I completely agree that a Foo[Bleh] is distinct from a Foo[Blah].  However,a Blah instance is by definition also a Bleh: the questions I'm really trying to get at is why, in absence of an explicit Foo[Blah], the compiler isn't using Blah as a Bleh and resolving the type class correctly?

Comment: @Refefer: I've updated my answer. If you'd like to know why type inference works with parameter groups one by one I can give you 2 reasons: 1) it's useful with lambda as last parameter; 2) it's faster.